# confused on how to properly assert a keystoneJS model save error with mocha + chai

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai, keystonejs

Cannot seem to figure out the proper pattern to throw and Chai assert a keystonejs (v 3.x) model error:

Ive got a simple model with a single "unique : true " string parameter parameter:
myModel {"uri":"http://google.com"}. 
THis test is meant to assert an error because there is an existing document with the same uri param value - and the

Here is my test:

```
it('should throw an error when create with duplicate unique uri param', function(done) {
    var myList = keystone.list('myModel');
     expect(function(){

       var newObj = new myList.model({
                uri: 'http://google.com'
        });

        newObj.save(function(err,doc){
          console.log(err); //properly instantiates MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index:
        if (err) throw new Error(err);
      });
    }).to.throw();
    done();
  });
```

This test fails with a:

```
  1) MyModel should throw an error when create with duplicate unique uri param:
     AssertionError: expected [Function] to throw an error
```

any idea on the proper pattern for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a decent pattern for this that works:

```
...
newObj.save(function(err,doc){
  if (err) {
    expect(err).to.match(/duplicate key/);
    done();
  }
  else {
    throw new Error("doc should not have been created");
  }
 });
```